# Search missing from Activities in Ubuntu 22

Tags: 22.04, search

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 20 --> Ubuntu 22. When pressing the super key (which goes to the activities window), I have lost the ability to use search. Usually I would start typing and search would be activated; now there isn't even a search text box. How can I get this back?

Thanks.

--- Update ---

Created a new test user (standard, not administrator), and observed the same behavior, still no search box comes up.

Additional question: is there a way to access the search feature that is not through the activities window? I'm fine if there is alternate way to access it.

--- Update 2 ---

When I press the super key, OR I press applications in top left, OR hitting the lower left switcher - they all go to the same place, all without a text box still. Haven't found a way yet to be able to access Ubuntu search by other means.

I assume that through either some themes, or wonky settings, that I have something different than vanilla Ubuntu 22 as far as themes go. Wondering if that's the issue.

Comment: Try creating a new account and see if the issue produces there. This allows at least to know whether this is an issue with the install or with your user configuration.

Comment: Add that information to your question. I would reinstall in that case.

Comment: I have upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and I can't reproduce your problem. To answer your "additional question", click on the **Show Applications** icon at the bottom of the Ubuntu Dock. It looks like 9 dots arranged in 3X3 square. You should see the search option there as well.